# Parsing images from rss

Tags: parsing, rss

I've been working recentlu on application which dynamicly load info from bbc web-page.
so my questions is - how can I parse rss images, using just standart GET and HEAD methods?

E. g. we have following page `http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/10209`
is it possible to somehow parse map of UK from that page, I know that there are no image of it, but only embedded flash application.

But my question is it possible to parse it. And of course if it possible, how can I do it?

Comment: This question is nothing to do with RSS (Really Simple Syndication)/web feeds. What "RSS" are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

What would you like to parse from an image? If it's its metadata, I think this is possible, also if you want to do some "image treatment". With the "content-type" answer (from HEAD), you can guess if the is about an image or something else. However, you have to download the image to get its metada (GET) and parse them or do some image manipulation on it...

If the image is embedded in a flash application, this looks much more challenging, I don't have much idea about how flash application are "compiled" and if its possible to get their "ressources" in a simple manner.

Good luck!